# Can you use split and nextLine?

Tags: java, csv

Let's say I had a scanner "in" that was assigned a one line CSV file, and I wanted to assign the values to an array, would I be able to do something like

```
String[] array = in.nextLine().split(",");
```

Comment: Yes, Because the `nextLine()` method return `String` type, you can use `split()` method to get an array of Strings.

Comment: Why not? The simplest way to find out is by executing your statement. Have you tried?

Comment: I have, but while I'm iterating through a file with multiple lines, it seems that I keep getting an infinite loop, so I'm trying to see any debugging I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as noted in the comments.  But you can also do this either reading from a string or from a file.

- set the delimiter to match on `0` or more spaces, followed by a `,` followed by `0` or more spaces.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("This, is , a ,test");
scanner.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

prints

```
This
is
a
test
```